# How can I move cards using Trello App for Slack?

Tags: trello, slack

I am struggling to find the way to move a Trello card using the [Trello App for Slack](https://trello.com/platforms/slack).

In the page From [The Trello App for Slack → /trello commands](http://help.trello.com/article/1049-slack-app) I can find multiple commands, but not the one to move cards through columns.

Does it exist?